# Password confirmation with spring annotation

Tags: java, maven, spring-security

Can someone please explain me the error I am getting. I am doing password confirmation by [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/registration-with-spring-mvc-and-spring-security).

```
2020-05-29 15:23:33.397 ERROR 10832 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : 
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction] with root cause

javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.example.onlineshop.model.User] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='Passwords don't match', propertyPath=, rootBeanClass=class com.example.onlineshop.model.User, messageTemplate='Passwords don't match'}
```

If I am not mistaken I am did everything correctly.

Here is my Registration controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showRegistration(WebRequest request, Model model) {
    User user = new User();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    return "registration";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView createNewUser(@Valid User user, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request, Errors errors) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    User userExists = userService.findUserByName(user.getName());
    if (userExists != null) {
        bindingResult
                .rejectValue("name", "errors.user",
                        "There is already a user registered with the name provided");
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        model.setViewName("registration");
    } else {
        userService.saveUser(user);
        model.addObject("successMessage", "User has been registered successfully");
        model.addObject("user", new User());
        model.setViewName("registration");
    }
    return model;
}
```

This is a service

```
public User saveUser(User user) {
    user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    user.setActive(true);
    Role userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("CUSTOMER");
    user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

This is my model. Sorry for the view. Complaining about too much code

- @Data
- @Builder
- @AllArgsConstructor
- @NoArgsConstructor
- @Entity
- @Table(name = "user")
- public class User {
- @Id
- @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
- @Column(name = "user_id")
- private int id;
- @Column(name = "name")
- @NotEmpty(message = "*Please enter your name")
- private String name;
- @Column(name = "email")
- @ValidEmail
- @NotEmpty(message = "*Please enter your email")
- private String email;
- @Column(name = "password")
- @NotEmpty(message = "*Please enter your password")
- @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password length should be at least 5   characters")
- private String password;
- @Transient
- private String matchingPassword;
- @Column(name = "active")
- private Boolean active;
- @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
- @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
- inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
- private Set roles;
- }

Comment: Include code _in the question_. More broadly, it looks like you're failing to correctly separate your data-transfer objects (DTOs) and persistence representations, which is particularly noticeable in a case like a "user" class where the password should _never_ be stored unhashed and an incoming request object may need to contain two copies of the password.

Comment: The error is about the custom @PasswordMatches annotation. You should ignore the condition for non-existing users.

Comment: On my UserDto I used @PasswordMatches and lombok annotations

Comment: Where is your model? Can we see that?

Comment: @Berk Could you please explain more briefly, how should I solve this problem. I still could not solve it

Comment: Just remove the @PasswordMatches annotation and see if it works properly, if it is, the implementation of the annotation has a problem. Your error code is complaining about that part because probably it is trying to match the password for a new user as well, a new user wouldn't have a password so it throws an error. You should probably use different DTOs for login and new user registration.